# Array JSON AngularJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I've one array with several objects in JSON, & a select carries an array. Depending on the selection of array, other select box get loaded which is just below it.

**Markup**

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-select col col-50">
    <div class="input-label">
      Mês
    </div>
    <select class="select-estado" 
            ng-model="mesSelecionado" 
            ng-options="meses.mes for meses in mes">
      <option value="">Selecione um mês</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>



<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input item-select col col-50">
    <div class="input-label">
      Estado
    </div>
    <select name="estados" class="select-estado" 
            ng-model="estadoSelecionado" 
            ng-options="mesSelecionadoAtual.estados as estados.estado for estados in mesSelecionadoAtual.estados">
      <option value="">Selecione um estado</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

**Problem**

When I put 2 in select box. the array which is generated ... It always selects the last house of the array: /

Does any one have idea what would be the reason behind it?

[**Problem Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPWVQK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed some angular bootstraps ...

```
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
  ...
})
```

Look at this codepen :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJpmYv

However, I would suggest you to take a look at the free chapters of angularjs at codeschool:

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Comment: thank you, and excuse the level of angularjs